# File not found Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, filenotfoundexception

I am having some problems with simple cloud storage ([simplecloud](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage)). When I run with Maven the console outputs following error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\key (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Source code is here : [src git](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pliablematter/cloudstorage/CloudStorage.java)

However it exists in the directory as shown here :

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

[image]

POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pliablematter</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-cloud-storage</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Simple Cloud Storage</name>
<description>A simple wrapper around the Google Cloud Storage API</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1beta2-rev6-1.15.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: From junit you should use a particular version and **NOT** `LATEST` cause if a new release comes out your build might fail. So in other words your build is not reproducible.

Comment: @David , DId you resolve this problem?. I run into the same problem.Can you please give me solution for this issue?

Comment: Hey when I put the key in the folder : /simple-cloud-storage/src/main/resources/var/ and did a clean maven build the project was running and I had a JAR file which worked. Sometimes the tests doesn't pass because you are limited to do x requests per second but 1 out of 10 it worked I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you post the related code snippet in your `CreateBucketTest`.

I believe in your test you are opening a file `\var\key`.  Obviously this is going to cause problem because the file you are thinking of is not really located at `\var\key`

Some suggestions to you:

1. instead of reading from absolute path, see if you can change it to opening stream for class path resources.
2. Put your `key` file under `src/main/test/resources`.  Assume you put it under `src/main/test/resources/cloudkey/key`
3. With the above setup, when you run your test, the `key` file will be under the classpath at location `/cloudkey/key`

---

Edit:

After reading a bit on your code, here are some suggestions:

First, your `getStorage` relies on system property which is not very test friendly. Consider writing your code in a more test-friendly way

However I believe you are not going to refactor your code anyway, here is one way you can do:

1. put `key` in `/src/test/resources`.  By doing so, when compiled, `key` will be put to `BASE_DIR/target/test-classes/key`.
2. Here I assume you will have only 1 key for all your tests.  What you need to do is to set the system property `private.key.path` with the correct path of `key`.  You can do so by configuring surefire plugin : http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html.  Add a `systemPropertyVariables` `private.key.path` with value `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/key`.  By doing so, when your test is running, the sys property `private.key.path` will be set with the correct value, so that your test should run fine.

Comment: I updated the post. I did what you suggested but still running on the error. I even placed it in every map of the project but still no effect.

Comment: They key is how you are reading the file.  it is not going to work by placing the file everywhere.  Try to understand what happen to the files you put under `src/` and how it is make available to your tests

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your \var\key directory is present in the target directory that Maven creates for the build. I'll go out on a limb and guess that it's probably not there now. If you have to have that \var\key in a non-standard place, you can use the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to copy it into the target directory. As @Adrian Shum suggests, test\resources would be a standard place for Maven to look to find it.

EDIT:

Seems like you wanted to explore this option, so here's how you might use the Maven Resources Plugin in your Maven POM...

Inside the plugins node under build, add:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
```

Then after the plugins node again inside build, add the directory or directories you need to copy over to target, for example:

```
<resources>
    <resource><directory>src/main/resources</directory></resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <testResource><directory>src/var/key</directory></testResource>
    <testResource><directory>src/test/resources</directory></testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: I just placed my var folder into target directory but when running the folder goes away and reports come in place.

Comment: Yes, this is why I mentioned that you should use the Maven Resources Plugin to copy the resources to the target directory. Wouldn't bother doing that if you are able to relocate the item you need to the test/resources tree, however--I find with Maven that I really don't like to fight it.

Comment: Added example in case you'll have to use the maven-resources-plugin. You may need to fiddle with the directory you have it copy for you--maybe you want src/var rather than src/var/key. Just get it synced up with the code so it can see a resource that exists in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the initial `\`. Also, as pointed out by the others, as this is obviously a test key (judging by the name), you should place it under `src/test/resources/var/key` and change your code to look for just `var/key/test.p12`.

Comment: It needed to be the absolute path instead of relative (didn't know)